# "live chart" x axis not updating with along with time WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, livecharts

I have just started exploring the live chart library however can't seem to get the x axis to update as time passes. I have gone over this time and time again and can't seem to find the problem. The data points update correctly which is what I am finding so confusing!

I will at a later date be replacing the DateTime with a timer that displays how long the test has been running instead, if that makes the solution any simpler?

Part of me thinks this must be something simple I am missing!?

I appreciate any help on this one!

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private double _axisMax;
    private double _axisMin;
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //To handle live data easily, in this case we built a specialized type
        //the MeasureModel class, it only contains 2 properties
        //DateTime and Value
        //We need to configure LiveCharts to handle MeasureModel class
        //The next code configures MEasureModel  globally, this means
        //that livecharts learns to plot MeasureModel and will use this config every time
        //a ChartValues instance uses this type.
        //this code ideally should only run once, when application starts is reccomended.
        //you can configure series in many ways, learn more at http://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Types%20and%20Configuration


        var mapper = Mappers.Xy<MeasureModel>()
            .X(model => model.DateTime.Ticks)   //use DateTime.Ticks as X
            .Y(model => model.Value);           //use the value property as Y

        //lets save the mapper globally.
        Charting.For<MeasureModel>(mapper);


        //the values property will store our values array
        ChartValues = new ChartValues<MeasureModel>();

        //lets set how to display the X Labels
        DateTimeFormatter = value => new DateTime((long)value).ToString("hh:mm:ss");

        AxisStep = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks;
        SetAxisLimits(DateTime.Now);

        //The next code simulates data changes every 300 ms
        Timer = new DispatcherTimer
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300)
        };
        Timer.Tick += TimerOnTick;
        IsDataInjectionRunning = false;
        R = new Random();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public ChartValues<MeasureModel> ChartValues { get; set; }
    public Func<double, string> DateTimeFormatter { get; set; }

    public double AxisStep { get; set; }

    public double AxisMax
    {
        get { return _axisMax; }
        set
        {
            _axisMax = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AxisMax");
        }
    }
    public double AxisMin
    {
        get { return _axisMin; }
        set
        {
            _axisMin = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AxisMin");
        }
    }

    public DispatcherTimer Timer { get; set; }
    public bool IsDataInjectionRunning { get; set; }
    public Random R { get; set; }

    private void RunDataOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsDataInjectionRunning)
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Timer.Stop();
            IsDataInjectionRunning = false;
        }
        else
        {
            stopwatch.Start();
            Timer.Start();
            IsDataInjectionRunning = true;
        }
    }

    private void TimerOnTick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) // Class is referencing from here!
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;

        ChartValues.Add(new MeasureModel
        {
            DateTime = DateTime.Now,
            Value = R.Next(0, 10)
        });

        SetAxisLimits(DateTime.Now);

        //lets only use the last 30 values
        if (ChartValues.Count > 30) ChartValues.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    private void SetAxisLimits(DateTime now)
    {
        AxisMax = now.Ticks + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20).Ticks; // lets force the axis to be 100ms ahead
        AxisMin = now.Ticks - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8).Ticks; //we only care about the last 8 seconds
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) // if subrscribed to event
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MeasureModel
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:graph_test_6"
    xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
    xmlns:chart="http://mindfusion.eu/charting/wpf" x:Class="graph_test_6.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Height="30" Click="RunDataOnClick">
        Inject/Stop Data
    </Button>
    <lvc:CartesianChart Grid.Row="1">
        <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
            <lvc:LineSeries Values="{Binding ChartValues}" PointGeometrySize="18" StrokeThickness="4" />
        </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:Axis LabelFormatter="{Binding DateTimeFormatter}" 
                      MaxValue="{Binding AxisMax}" 
                      MinValue="{Binding AxisMin}"
                      DisableAnimations="True">
                <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                    <lvc:Separator Step="{Binding AxisStep}"></lvc:Separator>
                </lvc:Axis.Separator>
            </lvc:Axis>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
    </lvc:CartesianChart>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="323,-71,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
</Grid>
```

[Screen shot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjXG7.jpg)

Comment: @3615 I believe the latest one. I downloaded it from here ... https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Install
thanks

Comment: Ok, but is there any difference from [this](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Constant%20Changes)? The code you posted seems to be identical to the example on the website. I'm currently running the latest version from sources on github and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Also created an new wpf app with your code to ensure all the differences from the example source are taking in consideration: [it's working](http://screencast.com/t/fLers3IbW). Or maybe I don't understand your problem.

Comment: @3615 I created another WPF just encase but still having the same problem. I have attached a screenshot link above (sorry not enough rep to embed) but the graph disappears off the screen and the time doesn't update

Comment: @3615 from what i can see its happening on your video as well

Comment: I wasn't understanding the problem you were trying to describe. The image helped me realize what's the problem. It's not related to livecharts, but to WPF bindings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Xaml you are binding for AxisX properties MaxValue and MinValue:

```
 MaxValue="{Binding AxisMax}" 
 MinValue="{Binding AxisMin}"
```

When window is loaded WPF mechanism reads the values that are bound: that's how you are getting initial values for X Axes. Later in code you are changing these values:

```
 AxisMax = now.Ticks + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20).Ticks; // lets force the axis to be 100ms ahead
 AxisMin = now.Ticks - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8).Ticks; //we only care about the last 8 seconds
```

Xaml should be notified about these changes and it's done via:

```
 OnPropertyChanged("AxisMin");
 OnPropertyChanged("AxisMax");
```

The problem is that window control itself doesn't declare, that it supports change notifications: it's missing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

So to fix your issue change

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
```

to

```
 public partial class MainWindow  : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much! Now to try and plot time elapsed rather than date time :)